# Connecting two Entity Relationship Diagrams

Tags: entity-relationship, enterprise-architect

I am having a huge project and the entity relationship diagram is looking pretty crowded. So I was thinking about to separate the big entity relationship diagram in two or maybe more diagrams.

But I can't find a proper way to do that and still have like an component diagram which I can connect the diagrams somehow ...

At this moment I am not even sure this is possible..

So if not is there at least a way to don´t show the bubble-attributes in your diagram?

Comment: What has this to do with EA? What is your issue here?

Comment: i have to do it with ea because of the company i am working for ... but the databases are to big to be shown properly in one big diagramm

Comment: Well, ok. Or not :-/ There's not much advise possible here. Better stick with small diagrams and create a wall paper by dragging the different diagrams into one. You can't show links between them, though. Making wall papers usually is just a waste of time.

Comment: I guess the question "why using EA for ERD" is futile?

Comment: Well actually this wall papers could solve exaclty my problem thanks!

Comment: EA is just the common tool they use in my company so they stick to that ...

Comment: If you tell me what you mean with "bubble atttributes" (provide a screen shot) I'll try to give some hints.